# mySQL best index for %word% queries

Tags: mysql, optimization, text, indexing

The MySQL docs say that a usual BTREE index will not help in queries where % is at the beginning of the query string like in

```
SELECT textcol FROM manytexts WHERE textcol LIKE '%word%';
```

Which index could help here? I am interested in retrieving specific phrases, where the word-by-word search of FULLTEXT indices are no help.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no index (like e.g. Postgres' trigram indexes) in MySQL that would support this kind of query. You will have to use the fulltext search for that.

Answer (score 0):

No indexes can help with queries `LIKE %%`. This predicate makes argument non-[sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for info. Can you explain, how they can use indexes?

Comment: See here: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/212-PostgreSQL-9.1-Trigrams-teaching-LIKE-and-ILIKE-new-tricks.html and here: http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/